# How is delta-v calculated for an interstellar journey?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, rockets, interstellar-travel, delta-v, alpha-centauri

Just recently I have been learning about orbital mechanics and I came across the following article:

https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/life-unbounded/why-chemical-rockets-and-interstellar-travel-dont-mix/

The delta-v value of 26,200 km/s for a journey to Alpha Centauri is calculated. I wanted to know how this number has been found

Comment: You omit one piece of data from the source. "**in a 100 year mission**". Include that, and you have enough data points to get a valid answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For interstellar voyages like that, the calculation is rather simple.

$$velocity = \frac{distance}{time}$$

Usually, we set a time limit for how much travel time is acceptable. In that article, they pick a 100 years.

Since we know both the distance to the target (4.37ly) and the travel time (100y), we can divide to get the required velocity. ($v = \frac{4.37}{100}c = 13100km/s$)

That's how fast we need to go to make it in a 100 years.. Since we start at pretty much zero, our *change in velocity* ("delta-v") is 13,100km/s. Of course, we need to stop too when we arrive, which is another 13,100km/s, for a total of 26,200km/.
Is 1000 years acceptable? then it's just 2,620km/s.

Comment: Quick question, what's to stop us from doing similar calculations to planets in the solar system?

Comment: @Ryan Generally, in the Solar System, you're calculating for currently-existing and near-future rockets  which only have the delta-V for modest speeds, and orbital mechanics are hard taskmasters. With projected interstellar spacecraft, the distances are _huge_, the spacecraft are _fast_, and the delta-V is plentiful,  so the point-and-burn approximation is often good enough.

Comment: @Ryan the math is only valid where earth and target orbital velocity are much smaller than the ship velocity. For Mars probes it starts at earth orbiting at 30kms and only adds around 3 extra to transfer, so different approach. People have calculated basic DV costs for the solar system and generated helpful maps https://www.reddit.com/r/space/comments/29cxi6/i_made_a_deltav_subway_map_of_the_solar_system/